# Convert PHP Regex to .NET

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

What's the equivalent below in .NET Regex

```
preg_replace("/\(([^()]*+|(?R))*\)/","", $string);
```

I always struggle with regex, I tried getting it right with myregextester.com and I just can't get the syntax right, so it turns this..

```
1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 9.0 \(3083\))
```

Into

```
1.0
```

I want to strip out the comments (even if nested)

I was using this but it didn't work for nested comments.

```
 Dim regex As New Regex(String.Format("\{0}.*?\{1}", "(", "("))
 Return regex.Replace(s, String.Empty)
```

Comment: Im sorry but why aren't you just using this: `\s*\(.*\)`

Comment: Do you want to match balanced parentheses?

Comment: *Matching Nested Constructs* in [Friedl's book p436](https://books.google.com/books?id=P5UXAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA328&ots=HAjQ68fgTv&hl=en&dq=mastering%20regular%20expressions%20nested%20constructs&pg=PA436#v=onepage&q=Matching%20Nested%20Constructs&f=false): `\((?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)`

Comment: IISMathwizard wizard solution seems to work for my needs - thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex under consideration is a PCRE regex matching balanced parentheses. To match balanced parentheses in .NET, you may use [this regex](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/377025):

```
\((?>(?:[^()])+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)
```

VB.NET implementation:

```
Dim R As Regex = New Regex(" \(                   " & _
                       "   (?>                " & _
                       "       [^()]+         " & _
                       "     |                " & _
                       "       \( (?<DEPTH>)  " & _
                       "     |                " & _
                       "       \) (?<-DEPTH>) " & _
                       "   )*                 " & _
                       "   (?(DEPTH)(?!))     " & _
                       " \)                   ", _
   RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
Dim str As String = R.Replace("1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 9.0 \(3083\))", "")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NdRfZH)

To remove the spaces, just add `[ ]*` or `\s*` at the beginning of the pattern.

In case you just want to remove all characters between the leftmost and rightmost round brackets, use greedy matching:

```
(?s)[ ]*\(.*\)
```

Or

```
(?s)\p{Zs}*\(.*\)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)%5B%20%5D*%5C(.*%5C)&i=1.0%20(Mac%20OS%20X%20Mail%209.0%20%5C(3083%5C))&r=)

The `\p{Zs}` Unicode category class matches any Unicode spaces, while `[ ]` matches a regular literal space. Note that `\s` matches all possible whitespace including newline symbols.

Comment: I tested "\s*\(.*\)" and "(?s)[ ]*\(.*\)" They both behave the same, in my testing, can you provide a sample where the outcome will be different.

Comment: E.g. `\s` can match a line break, and `[ ]` cannot.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now, "(?s)[ ]*(.*)" is what I'm looking for, in this situation I have - I don't think a line break is possible, but if it was. Thanks for the education.

Comment: You may read more about [what `\s` matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#sectionToggle7) at MSDN.  In a nutshell, it matches `\f` (form feed character), `\n` (newline character), `\r` (carriage return character), `\t` (tab character), `\v` (vertical tab character), `\x85` (ellipsis or NEXT LINE (NEL) character (…)), `\p{Z}` (that matches any separator character). Those last ones can be checked at [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) or at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm).